# Как массив сгенерированых чисел использовать в switch case

Tags: android, случайные-числа

Всем привет!
Есть Fragments между которыми я переключаюсь нажатием кнопки используя swich case и random. Но рандом дублирует числа и поэтому открываются Фрагменты повторно, а мне этого не нужно.

Почитав в интернете об этом, я решил создать массив из чисел. Теперь при загрузи активити создается рандомный массив без повторяющихся чисел.

Вопрос, как мне использовать этот сгенерировавшийся массив в switch case, который у меня используется в обработчике нажатия кнопки onClickNext. И потом еще "определить" действия при завершении массива.

Кто мне поможет? Кто подскажет? За любую информацию спасибо!

```
Set<Integer> generated = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (max < numbersNeeded)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't ask for more numbers than are available");
        }
        Random rng = new Random();                                  // Ideally just create one instance globally
                                                                                     // Note: use LinkedHashSet to maintain insertion order
        generated = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        while (generated.size() < numbersNeeded) {
            next = rng.nextInt(max) + 1;
                                                                                   // As we're adding to a set, this will automatically do a containment check
            generated.add(next);
            Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);

        }
    }



    public void onClickNext(View view) {


            switch (next) {
                case 1: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);

                }
                break;
                case 2: {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);


                }
                break;
                case 3: {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);


                }
                break;

                case 4: {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);


                }
                break;
                case 5: {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);


                }
                break;

                default: {
                   // Log.d(TAG, "Here:" + next);


                }
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: интересно у меня у одного чувство, что вы очень простую задачи хотите решить, как-то своим путем. МБ расскажите, что вы в целом хотите ибо сейчас можно только гадать. ЧТо после нажатия на кнопку должно быть, перейти на рандомный фрагмент?

Comment: Да, по клику на кнопку я перехожу на рандомный фрагмент. Фрагменты это вопросы Quiz, поэтому они не должны повторяться.

Comment: А почему бы тогда не сделать немного иначе. У вас есть массив фрагментов допустим 6. И вы достаете из массива рандомный исходя из размера массива, удаляете из массива, и запускаете экземпляр. Кажется этот вариант намного проще.

Comment: Да, наверно можно и так,  но я походу создания приложения учусь и сейчас я вижу такой алгоритм действий,  как описал в вопросе,  если это приведет в тупик или будет не осуществимо, буду разбираться с предложенной вами схемой...но программирование мне нравиться тем, что всегда есть выход).

Comment: Но в любом случае Вам нужно рандомно или подряд достать и удалить (что бы не было повторов) элемент из коллекции. В Вашем случае взять элемент из `generated` и присвоить переменной `next`, далее по плану.